# How to specify ID when use set-reviewers

Tags: gerrit

Can you please tell me how can I specify my 'commit id' or change id when I use 'gerrit set-reviewers?

I tried using both commit id and change id, but they both said 'no such change'.
I copy and paste these values from the http://gerrit.mycompany:8081/#/c/770/

```
 ssh -p 23518 mps-gerrit.sj.broadcom.com gerrit set-reviewers --project test_project -a test@mycompany.com 0876e0aacd071b64a9b8b85df8a383ffba2d0447
fatal: "0876e0aacd071b64a9b8b85df8a383ffba2d0447" no such change
```

How can I fix my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the change exists on Gerrit:

```
ssh -p <port> <user>@<host> gerrit query 'status:open project:<project_name> owner:self'
```

The output will be something like this:

```
change I373eb10e309f5a7dbec6c7a0530fdde6c0036a1a
  project: project_name
  branch: branch_name
  id: I373eb10e309f5a7dbec6c7a0530fdde6c0036a1a
  number: 127860
  subject: commit msg
  owner:
    name: user
    email: user@example.com
    username: user_name
  url: https://host/127860
  createdOn: 2013-11-05 11:40:31 EST
  lastUpdated: 2013-11-05 12:06:48 EST
  sortKey: 0028e8220001f374
  open: true
  status: NEW

type: stats
rowCount: 1
runTimeMilliseconds: 24
```

Then if it exists the `changeId` (I373eb10e309f5a7dbec6c7a0530fdde6c0036a1a) the `number` (127860) and `commit hash` can be used to set the reviewer:

```
ssh -p <port> <user>@<host> gerrit set-reviewers --project "<project_name>" -a user1@example.com I373eb10e309f5a7dbec6c7a0530fdde6c0036a1a
```

more info can be found [here](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-set-reviewers.html)